# Get a list of site collection - Powershell

Tags: sharepoint, powershell

I am using the following PowerShell script to get a list of site collection for a web application. it works but url column cuts of after 25 or 30 letters. Any fix for this?

```
Get-SPSite -WebApplication http://myCompany.bofa.com:9966 -Limit All | `
  Select -ExpandProperty AllWebs | select url, Title, Created > c:\mysite.txt
```

Where I output to a file or screen same outcome where the url cuts off after 25 or 30 characters.

Result looks like this:

```
http://mycompany.bofa.co.... Site Title   8/12/2012 3:49:20 PM
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
Get-SPSite -WebApplication http://myCompany.bofa.com:9966 -Limit All | 
  Select -ExpandProperty AllWebs | 
ft url, Title, Created -auto > c:\mysite.txt
```

if it were not enough you can try this:

```
Get-SPSite -WebApplication http://myCompany.bofa.com:9966 -Limit All | 
  Select -ExpandProperty AllWebs | 
ft url, Title, Created -auto | 
out-string -width 1024 > c:\mysite.txt # 1024 can me more or less depends the length you need
```

Comment: is -auto a powershell 3 or 2 operator? cause I get parameter auto cannot be found

Comment: @ShawnTorres both! is `-autosize` to be correct! but `-auto` can work too

Comment: @ShawnTorres Here is a technet article for more details: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347677.aspx